# Is the function rlim existing in Octave?

Tags: plot, octave

Does a function exist that is similar to rlim in matlab? I need to modify a polar plot for an antenna diagram where the 0 is on the outer rim and all values are negative.

The result should in general (!) look like this picture. Only the scaling (not the ticks) on the radial axes is relevant, though.

[image]

Comment: No rlim, but you can adjust your r accordingly to get the same curve, then the 'rtick' range, and then adjust the labels manually. You may have to enable "showhiddenhandles" from the root graphics object to enable you to go through the graphics object hierarchy to do the last part.

Comment: That sounds quite laborious. I will have to look whether I can manage it. Nonetheless many thanks for your answer!

Comment: It wouldn't be more than 4-5 lines of code, but of course it might depend on the exact plot you're after. If you wanted to share an example plot and what you're after, I don't mind having a go writing a function for you.

Comment: Many thanks in advance, I put a picture into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll provide an example for the sake of demonstrating what I was on about:

```
t = 0 : 0.01 : 2 * pi;
r = abs( 2 + 5 * sin( 3 .* t ) .* ( 1 + 2 * pi .* t - t .^ 2 ) );
p = polar( gca, t, r );

set( groot, 'showhiddenhandles', 'on' )
TTicks = [ 0  : 45 : 315 ];  % Note: here, specified in degrees
RTicks = [ 20 : 20 : 100 ];  % Note: 'zero' not included!
set( gca, 'ttick', TTicks );
set( gca, 'rtick', RTicks );

NumTticks = length( TTicks );
NumRticks = length( RTicks );   % will only be correct if zero was excluded above.

PolarGrid = findobj( gca, 'tag', 'polar_grid' );
Handles = get( PolarGrid, 'children' );
NumHandles = length( Handles );

% The children are arranged as follows:
%   NumTticks handles: text objects that make up the ttick labels (from last to first)
%   NumTticks handles: line objects that make up the ttick gridlines
%   NumRticks handles: text objects that make up the rtick labels (from last to first)
%   NumRticks handles: line objects that make up the rtick concentric gridlines
%   Last handle      : A darker line, coinciding with the last rtick gridline, serving as the outline.

% Therefore, to change the rticklabels:
RTickLabelHandles = Handles( NumHandles - NumRticks - [1 : NumRticks] );
RTickLabels = { '', '30db', '20db', '10db', '0' };
for i = 1 : NumRticks, set( RTickLabelHandles(i), 'string', RTickLabels{i} ), end;
```

But, having said that, if your requirements deviate to such an extent from what the `polar` function is expected to provide (including a custom 0 angle orientation), then you're right, it's probably better to simply draw all the elements yourself from scratch (including grid circles and custom labels).

Comment: I will have to look through your code thoroughly (many thanks for it!). The data I have to show are regularly measurement data with values between 0 and eg -50. I think I have an idea now how to move on.

Comment: @Jürgen one thing I noticed (which does make some sense, but I was still surprised to see it was the case) is that you cannot specify negative rticks. Octave will simply ignore them (and also a zero rtick). So if you do want to get rticks with 'negative' values appearing on them, you'll have to create your plot on fake positive axes that behave the way you want, and then 'relabel' the axes to display the negative values that you want them to show. (this workaround is not uncommon in octave/matlab in general)

Comment: A valuable hint, I will keep it in mind!