# How to make a personalized Theta tick labels in the Polar plot in Octave?

Tags: plot, octave, polar-coordinates

So I'm making a octave code based in a MatLab one. In some point, he does that.

```
polar(deg2rad(graphTheta),graphLumints);
title(['Azimuth angles = ' num2str(fixedAzimuthAngle)...
    ' and ' num2str(fixedAzimuthAngle+180)]);
thetaticks(0:10:350);
thetaticklabels({'0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100',...
    '110','120','130','140','150','160','170','180','170','160','150',...
    '140','130','120','110','100','90','80','70','60','50','40','30',...
    '20','10'})

ax=gca;
ax.RAxisLocation=280;
ax.ThetaZeroLocation='top';
```

Witch results in a polar plot that goes from 0 to 180, and then from 180 back to 0, like this:

[The polar plot I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH0Be.png)

But since Octave donesn't have this thetaticklabels function, I have no ideia what I should do.

The nearest I got was doing this:

```
aux = [0:10:180];
set(gca,"rtick", 0:20:80, "ttick", aux);
polar(deg2rad(graphTheta),graphLumints);
cam_pos = get(gca, 'CameraPosition');
cam_pos(3) = -cam_pos(3);
campos ([0, 0, -1]);
camroll(180);
set(gca, 'CameraPosition', cam_pos);
set(gca, "rtick", 0:20:80,"ttick",aux);
polar(deg2rad(graphTheta),graphLumints);
```

And give me this:
[Nearest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmA6D.png)

In this case, the plot is right, he kind of mirrored the thing, that is what I want, but the degrees labels are wrong, anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: might this be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283752/4183191