# customization of rticks and tticks in polarplot made using octave

Tags: plot, octave

[polar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi2VI.png) I am trying to customize the labels of theta to get them displayed in a clockwise direction but the default is anticlockwise and I also wanted to have the background transparent in octave

I tried to use rticks and tticks but there was no use!! Any feature that can help in octave to resolve this?

Comment: `axis("ij")` will flip the y-axis (even in a polar plot). Transparency is not really supported, so no help there.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
set( gca, 'xdir', 'reverse' )
```

as a simple solution it will probably have the effect you want.

For more complex manipulations, this old post may also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283752/4183191

As for "transparent background", this could mean a number of things. If you care to elaborate further I might try to answer that too.